# Android Studio: How do I create sliding tab navigation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm fairly new to Android Development so I'm a little lost. I am trying to make a app with a sliding tab type navigation to get to different screens.

I've been googling it for like hours and I can't seem to find anything that breaks it down enough for me to understand. From what I read, I would have to use fragments? Right now, I just have my all my screens as separate activities, which I probably would have to change if I'm trying to do this, right?

I haven't really written any code besides messing with the xml so I don't really have much to show.

Anyway, if someone could explain to me how to do this that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with using the new project wizard and selecting "Tabbed Activity"?

[image: tabbed activity]

Comment: I tried using that but I couldn't figure out how to add more pages. When I tested it out, it just used the same xml for each tab

Comment: Right, each tab is a fragment. You can copy the example code, create a new fragment, and change the layout.

Comment: what exactly would I have to copy? And to make a new fragment, would I just create a new layout xml?

Comment: Copy the entire `PlaceholderFragment` class and you can copy the layout xml if you feel like it would be a good starting point. Then you return the diiferent fragments from your `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem`.

Comment: So, when I did that and ran it, it seems to be switching fragments but when it switches to the 2nd fragment it crashes. Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: um, no... post the exception, or make another question about your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Viewpager** with **PagerTitleStrip**..

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.ContainerFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

here is the ContainerFragment..

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ContainerFragment extends    android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

ViewPager mViewPager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

public NewsContainerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), this);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

Here is the adapter..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;



public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {



public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
   }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FirstFrag();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFrag();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ThirdFrag();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return "FIRST FRAG";
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return "SECOND FRAG";
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return "THIRD FRAG";
    } else {
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
  }
}
```